# how to make SIMPLE animated sprite actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, flashdevelop, flash-builder

I cant find any well explained SIMPLE way of creating animated sprite. Lets say I have 2 .png files to appear rabbit running:

**rabbit1.png** and
 **rabbit2.png**

```
 [Embed(source='assets/rabbit1.png')] public static const R1: Class;
 [Embed(source='assets/rabbit2.png')] public static const R2: Class;
```

i know i can create sprite and add to it frames like this:

```
var rabbit1:Bitmap = new R1();
var rabbit2:Bitmap = new R2();

var bunny:Sprite = new Sprite();
bunny.addChildAt(rabbit1,1);
bunny.addChildAt(rabbit2,2);
```

That is OK, but how to animate it in SIMPLE way ?
(withour creating extra xml file or like)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just create the animation in a SWF and load that instead of the two images?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Good point,but I'm not using Adobe expensive prog, so I haven't yet found way of making swf transparent file with non-Adobe solutions,( do you know any?)

Comment: Never used it but this thing might do the job: http://vectorian.com/. You could also download the free demo.

Comment: yep I'm using it, can't figure out how to make transparent though

Comment: I'd be surprised if it doesn't support it. SWFs produced in the Flash IDE have transparent backgrounds by default. Are you sure that's not the case with vectorian?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet you are right ! just tested it does make things transparent. That's great news now i can generate my .swf files. So I was under wrong impression. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would create a class, lets say, 'SimpleAnimation', but if you don't want to there is another way (using your code)

```
var rabbit1:Bitmap = new R1();
var rabbit2:Bitmap = new R2();

var bunny:Sprite = new Sprite();
var currFrame:int = 0;
bunny.addChildAt(rabbit1,0);
bunny.addChildAt(rabbit2,1);
bunny.getChildAt(1).visible = false;

bunny.addEventListener(Event:ENTER_FRAME, onBunnyFrame);
function onBunnyFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var maxFrame:int = bunny.numChildren;
    bunny.getChildAt(currFrame).visible = false;
    currFrame++;
    currFrame = currFrame % maxFrame;
    bunny.getChildAt(currFrame).visible = true;
}
```

Comment: That's the idea, however don't create and addChild many Bitmaps like that: instead, swap one Bitmap's .bitmapData property.